partial function version of the Ackermann function must be total
In mcs.pdf, it has Problem 7.25. (I only solve somewhat important problems referred to in the chapter contents because I have learnt one Discrete Mathematics book before and read mcs to ensure no importants things are  omitted.)

One version of the the Ackermann function $A:\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ is defined recursively by
the following rules:
$$
  \begin{align*}
    A(m, n)&::=2n
 &&\text{if } m = 0 \text{ or } n \le 1,
 &(\text{A-base})\\
A(m, n)&::=A(m-1,A(m,n-1))
 &&\text{otherwise}
 &(AA)
  \end{align*}
$$
Prove that if $B:\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ is a partial function that satisfies this same definition,
then $B$ is total and $B=A$.

This problem is a bit weird since we can directly prove $A$ is total based on the definition and get the unique value of $A(m,n)$ as what wikipedia says by decreasing one of $m,n$ at each step until $m=0$ or $n=1$ where we can use the base case). Then why is the (partial) function $B$ needed?
(This question is edited after hinted by JulioDiEgidio's comment. As this comment says, I directly edit the question instead of using "Edited:" delimeter)

@JulioDiEgidio Thanks for your comment. But it seems that you didn't take "IMHO ..." in account. I said we could directly get that  total function without the assumption of the partial function.

@JulioDiEgidio Thanks. That is also said in the 3rd paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function after your hints. I understand now. Then the assumption seems to be reasonable. But why does the problem assume one function $B$ and prove $B$ is same as $A$ instead of directly proving $A$ is total? This seems to beat around the bush unnecessarily.

@JulioDiEgidio 1. Sorry, I missed saying proving A is well-defined. As the question says, the wikipedia reference gives one recursive process to calculate the unique value for each $A(m,n)$. So $B$ is not necessary. 2. After rethoughts, it seems the book expected proof and the wikipedia one is different. Is it that case? If so, could you give one for the book proof (If such a proof is not available, it is still ok to close this question since I have understood the proof in wikipedia)?

Eventually, I have repacked my comments into an answer.  I have taken your question to be asking "how do I read this", not "how do I solve it": the latter should be another question, and hopefully one where you give enough context for people not to have to read the whole book to know how to help... (here you have not even given the page of the exercise).

By reading Section 7.3, I think it is like e.g. with the "Collatz recurrence", where that constant function is one and maybe not the only one function satisfying the definition/specification. Here, assuming $B$ is a function that satisfies the "Ackermann recurrence", 1) prove that it is total; and, 2) I suppose they mean, prove it is unique: i.e., with functional extensionality, prove that, for any such $A$ and $B$, for every input, $A$ and $B$ return the same output -- or, I don't know what they mean.
Incidentally, note that in that context "function" and "partial function" are simply synonym, i.e. every function is born as a partial function, and one has to prove if a (partial) function is total.
Notice also that the WP article on the Ackermann function gives definitions that are not even easily seen equivalent to the one you are given in the book: also, at the very place you have linked, WP only gives a sketch of an argument for termination/totality, while you are asked to prove it (rigorously?) and using the framework, axioms, and definitions that are given in the book.
And your book is indeed more "sophisticated" than WP, since you are given a recurrence and have to consider the functions that fit the bill.  And the last question in the exercise, as said, I simply read: prove that there is one and only one function that satisfies that recurrence.
